# BigQuery get unique rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

[image: ROWS]

I have this rows, i would like to know how to only get the unique rows grouped by id, unit_number, serial number and driver, but at the same time get the date of that row

```
 SELECT
  id,
  date
  FROM
    `table`
  GROUP BY 
  id,
  date
  ORDER BY
    id, date DESC
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Edit tags. Extract date part from full date/time and include that, not the raw `date` field. Use Format function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an aggregation function:

```
SELECT id, unit_number, MAX(date)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY id, unit_number
ORDER BY id, MAX(date) DESC
```